# STM32 SD SPI FR_DISK_ERR

Tags: stm32, spi, sd, card

Hi I am working on STM32F103c8t6 MCU.I am trying to run sd card with spi wiht this library https://github.com/eziya/STM32_SPI_SDCARD do every thing like youtube video and my connection is like video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spVIZO-jbxE&t=321s.
This is a part of my cod:

```
send_uart("SD program ready....\r\n");
    
DSTATUS my_status = SD_disk_initialize(0);
 if(my_status == STA_NOINIT ){
    send_uart ("error in initializing SD CARD...\n");
 }else send_uart ("SD initializing OK...\n");
 
 if (my_status == STA_NODISK){
    send_uart ("No medium in the drive...\n");
 }
 if (my_status == STA_PROTECT){
    send_uart (" Write protected...\n");
 }
 
 fresult = f_mount(&fs, "0:", 1);
sprintf(buffer,"mounting SD CARD result:%d\n",fresult);
send_uart(buffer);  

/* Create second file with read write access and open it */
fresult = f_open(&fil, "file2.txt", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
sprintf(buffer,"open SD CARD result:%d\n",fresult);
send_uart(buffer);  

strcpy (buffer, "This is File2.txt, written using ...f_write... and it says Hello from 
Controllerstech\n");
fresult = f_write(&fil, buffer, bufsize(buffer), &bw);
sprintf(buffer,"write SD CARD result:%d\n",fresult);
send_uart(buffer);
```

This is my response from uart:

```
SD program ready....
SD initializing OK...
mounting SD CARD result:1
open SD CARD result:1
write SD CARD result:9
```

return SD initializing OK.. but mounting SD CARD result:1 that means FR_DISK_ERR.
What is the problem ?
Iam using a SD module that has a 5v to 3v level shifter ic it can cuse problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried different SD cards? Some manufacturers don't implement SPI mode very well in their SD cards.

Comment: I tried this module and this SD card with arduino it worked very well

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions [here on eziya76's blog](https://blog.naver.com/eziya76/221188701172) using the STM32CubeMX tool to generate your project and then adding/editing all the relevant driver code?

Comment: Yes I a mention in description I do every thing like video .when I do not insert SD card f_mount returned FR_NOT_READY .And initializing of SD card returned ok.

Comment: Compare the steps you've followed from the video with everything written down in the blog. Make sure that nothing is left out.

Comment: OK I am following line by line exactly the same with blog code